# When to use XOR and when to use IFF?

Tags: if-statement, xor, rule, declarative, paradigms

Since ((NOT A) XOR B) and A→B ("iff....then") (~A→~B) are logically same (e.g. login can not happen unless authentication happens) does that have any practical use or is just a logic tautology and the programmer can decide arbitrarily where to use XOR and where to use if...then?

An example rewrite is payment→delivery ("iff payment() == 'complete' then delivery()") rewritten to ((NOT payment()) XOR delivery())

EDIT: Truth table

A: payment
B: delivery

```
A  B  A' (A→B) (A' XOR B) (A' OR B)
T  T  F    T      T           T
T  F  F    F      F           F
```

Where the failure is

```
A  B  A' (A→B) (A' XOR B) (A' OR B)
T  F  F    F      F           F
```

And that a case where A is false is simply a false B and all of the below just means that B is false (since NOT A).

```
A  B  A' (A→B) (A' XOR B) (A' OR B)
F  T  T    T      F           T
F  F  T    T      T           T
```

or `goal → score ^ ¬goal→¬score` so that there is determinism and no other way (you can't score if you don't make a goal).

Comment: I'm not sure they are the same, at least not in an imperative language... e.g. how would ((NOT A) XOR B) select from one of two different code paths to take?

Comment: I didn't assume a language yet (maybe prolog or other rule-based to simplify what is done) but if we think simply `passwordmatch→login` we can write that logic like an XOR i e `((NOT passwordmatch) XOR login)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A→B is equivalent to (A' OR B). These are logically the same and can be used interchangeably.

Construct truth tables for A→B and (A' XOR B) and you'll see they are not logically equivalent.

EDIT: Here's the truth table

EDIT2: Updated truth table with (B iff A), which yes, is logically equivalent to (A' XOR B) and can be used interchangeably.

```
A  B  A' (A→B) (A' XOR B) (A' OR B)    (B iff A)
T  T  F    T      T           T           T
T  F  F    F      F           F           F
F  T  T    T      F           T           F
F  F  T    T      T           T           T
```

Comment: Thanks! `~A→~B ^ A→B` is exactly what I'm talking about. There can be no B with no A.